# Prove that the 1000th derivative of $\sin^{10}( \sinh^{10}(\exp(x^{10}) -1))$ is $1$ in $0$ using Taylor-Mclaurin.

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove this statement using taylor

> The $1000$th derivative of $ \sin^{10}(\sinh^{10}(\exp(x^{10})   -1))$ in $0$ is $1$.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it is.

Comment: What does "in $0$" mean here?

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm mistaken, the $1000$th derivative is not $1$, but rather $1000!$. Here's my thought process:
$$\exp(x^{10})-1 = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{10n}}{n!} = x^{10} + O(x^{20})$$
$$\sinh^{10}(\exp(x^{10})-1) = x^{100} + O(x^{110})$$
$$\sin^{10}(\sinh^{10}(\exp(x^{10})-1)) = x^{1000} + O(x^{1010})$$
Thus, the value of the $1000$th derivative divided by $1000!$ is $1$, so the $1000$th derivative evaluated at $0$ is $1000!$.

Comment: Hi. I have a question about the last step. If you derive only x^1000 why you don't lose information about the function?

Comment: The idea is that only the $x^{1000}$ term contributes to the evaluation of the 1000th derivative. All the lower powers will be prematurely killed off by the repeated differentiation, while the higher powers will have an $x^n$ even after all the derivatives, so those terms become 0 when we plug in $x=0$.